# nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

```
nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
```

So I'm getting this appear in the console and I'm not sure whether it is an issue that I should be bothered about or not. I noticed it after attaching my app to Firebase and writing to the database with anonymous sign in. Just wondering whether I need to do anything about this and if so what those actions would be.

Thanks!

Comment: By *console*, do you mean the Firebase Console?

Comment: I am getting the same thing. Xcode 8 console when running my app in the simulator.

Comment: Is that an iOS10 issue?  There's a known issue that crashes an app only if you run it with iOS 10 Simulator.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is a bug with logs in Xcode8 + iOS10.

---

We can get round it in this way:

When on **simulator**, add the Name `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and the Value
Variables `disable` and check it (Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Environment).

[image]

When on **device**, only add `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and check it（don't add the Value). You'll see the NSLog in the Xcode8 Console.

[image]

Comment: How do you set different environment variables for simulator versus device? I've never seen that before.

Comment: I have no idea what this does but for sure it works. Thanks a bunch !

Comment: This didn't work for me running Xcode 8.2.1 on iOS 10.2

Comment: @Alex, it works in XCode 8.2.1, I work in it too. Check, did you correct set the name and value.

Comment: Still a bug in xCode Version 9.2 (9C40b).

Answer (score 8):

Cause: iOS 10 & Xcode 8. Also can be replicated by an odd inputField bug:

> Issue belongs to an InputField whom width is smaller than the inputs
>   chars : 96px vs (4 * 28px) 
>   This leads to a 100% CPU and it is fixed
>   when width is set to 128px

[Link to the above fix and reasoning](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1066)

Or just silence everything:

- Press ⌘<
- Edit **simulator** scheme by adding or setting the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` under Environment Variables in the Run Arguments to a value of `disable`.
- Do the same for the **device** but remove the value for `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` , leaving it empty. The logs will display for the device as they should.

Comment: It would have been nice if you'd included a link to the information you're quoting.

Comment: I don't see how this is even related to the question? There are two answers that mention setting OS_ACTIVITY_MODE=disable which is the correct solution.

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer in a video on Reddit located here:  https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/5p0fvy/xcode_nw_host_stats_add_src_recv_too_small/

This warning comes from XCode and can be disabled by adding an Environmental variable to the Scheme's Run section.  The Environmental name is OS_ACTIVITY_MODE and the value is "disable".

This appears to suppress all of the "nw_" warning messages.  Note that this just *suppresses* the warnings.  I'm not sure if the warnings are significant or not or whether this indicates that there are "real" underlying problems that should be fixed.

[How to edit a Scheme's Run Environmental Variables section in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S71yT.png)

[Adding the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE value of "disable"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruqKH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exact same error message on Xcode-8.2 iOS-10.2, but I was not using Firebase, so I'm not sure if that makes a difference. Setting `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to `disable` did not solve the problem, however, I realized it was coming from the `All Exceptions Breakpoint` I had set. I changed it to from `All` to `Objective-C` (removing `C`) and it no longer stops on that line anymore. You can do this by right-clicking on breakpoint in the breakpoints tab on the left, then selecting edit, then making the change.