# AFNetworking Crash Report in Console

Tags: ios, afnetworking, crash-reports

In my demo, I am calling API by using AFNetworking SDK not by installing cocoapod and my code work is below,

```
    strURL = @"http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all";

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:strURL parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

This code work gives me proper result as per the API but during API call I got following crash report in my console.

[image]

Does anyone knows what are these errors are and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you run it on Simulator?

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos Yes `X-code 8.2` and simulator `iphone - 7+`

Comment: I think you should give a try using a physical device and see if the error still appears

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos Still Crashing

Comment: Somewhere else is the problem, the code that you have pasted is corrected (I tested it). Do you use anything else that my conflicts?

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos I just create new project and add `AFNetworking` SDK and in `VDL` i write this above code and add `transport layer` in plist and run the project. Thats all I have.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It might be an Apple's internal bug and you may also need to update the version of Xcode to the latest one (8.3)

Check out the following answer

[nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273773/nw-host-stats-add-src-recv-too-small-received-24-expected-28)

I tested the same code as you (running Xcode 8.3) and that is my console output

[image]