# React native - connection has no connection handler error meaning?

Tags: ios, react-native, connection

I created a new react project and when I run it on iOS from xcode, the console gives me this:

```
2017-05-19 23:25:34.119 [info][tid:main][RCTBatchedBridge.m:77] Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x6100001a6c80> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6100000c46e0>, executor: RCTJSCExecutor)
2017-05-19 23:25:51.287 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:295] Running application test ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2017-05-19 23:25:51.289 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Running application "test" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
2017-05-19 23:25:51.299771-0400 test[21948:1121429] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 3 Connection has no connected handler
2017-05-19 23:25:53.335282-0400 test[21948:1121426] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 4 Connection has no connected handler
2017-05-19 23:25:55.349190-0400 test[21948:1120112] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 5 Connection has no connected handler
```

What do `2017-05-19 23:25:51.299771-0400 test[21948:1121429] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 3 Connection has no connected handler` these lines mean and how to I resolve the issue?

I first noticed this when I tried to use fetch in my application and found it did not work. I found these messages in the console and later discovered these messages are happening with all my applications so I assume that means it is a config issue on my part?

I created a new test program to test what was causing this and found it happens on a brand new project. Below is my code is that generated the log output above:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => test);
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try Below process

**Xcode menu -> Product -> Edit Scheme...**

**Environment Variables -> Add -> Name: "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE", Value:"disable"**

**Run your app again**

Comment: Thank you! That worked, would you mind explaining why that worked?

Comment: This is not a solution, this is hiding errors. A real fix has not been found yet: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10027

Comment: Actually, I found that my iPhone app, which has been working fine for years, suddenly stopped being able to talk to my web services.  Adding this Environment Variable, and rebuilding/deploying the app fixed the error....  So, for me, this did more than just hiding a few error messages.

Comment: This will hide your NSLog's when using a real device. Change the 'disable' value to an empty string when testing on a real device. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41828707/672989

Comment: I still got the error. Even though I started react-devtools

Comment: Thanks for mentioning react-devtools @MarkThien I turned on remote JS debugging and could not figure out why my screen was blank and wouldn't load anything with debug messages showing connection failure.

It was trying to connect to a debugger. Installing the standalone react-native debugger helped solve my problem https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/master/packages/react-devtools

Comment: "the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE solution became useless with IOS 11, as it blocks all NSLog statements, not only system logs. In our case, no log anymore - which I had a hard time linking to this hack I put in place before!" ([source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10027))

Comment: This is not a solution as Ulises says This just bypass the warning.

Answer (score 19):

I figured out the solution:

To turn off Verbose for OS Activity Mode

1. From the xcode menu, Project -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme.
2. Then select `Run` on the left and then select `Arguments` tab on the right.
3. In `Environment Variables` add the name `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and value as `disable`.

Or see picture below.

[image]

Note: credit for image goes to [Ramkrishna Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40463835/1078829)

Answer (score 10):

This error is most likely from the websocket that is built into react-native to connect to the react-devtools. If you aren't running react-devtools while debugging, then you will get this error, and it also pumps a bunch of messages across the bridge complaining about not being able to open the websocket (you will only see those errors if you are using something like [rn-snoopy](https://github.com/jondot/rn-snoopy)).

The error will stop as soon as you install and open react-devtools. See these instructions for how to do it:
https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/master/packages/react-devtools/README.md

Comment: I'm running React Native on an iPad.   I can't see how to tell it to connect to the react-devtools on my dev machine - ideas?

Comment: So you're implying the react-devtools is somehow required for running react native? That's odd...

Answer (score 2):

To disable the websocket streams I did the following:

- in xcode: Libraries/React.xcodeproj/React/Inspector/RCTInspectorPackagerConnection.m: find `- (void)connect {` and add `return;` just after it.
- in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js: replace `if (__DEV__)` with `if (false)`

this is quite ugly but a lot better than the OS_ACTIVITY solution, as it does not hide or prevent any other debugging tools.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to a firewall application (Little Snitch) that never requests access when running from a react-native app. Steps that work for me:

- Open Safari browser in the simulator
- Visit google.com or any domain
- Make sure it opens the page. It will ask for access, etc
- Restart your app in simulator
- Restart logging `react-native log-ios`

That should help.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and my app's startup was significantly delayed because of the issue. The actual fix for me is detailed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10027#issuecomment-334681203), but I'll rewrite it in case the link breaks:

1. Open Xcode
2. Click `Product` on the top bar
3. Click `Scheme`, scroll down to `Edit Scheme`
4. Select `Run` on the left bar, `Info` on the top tab
5. Change `Build Configuration` from `Debug` to `Release`

Now the app not only no longer has the errors, it starts up much faster. The other "fixes" only hide the error.

Comment: This isn't helpful at all, you're just building for release every time just to avoid getting such error? makes no sense, and you can't debug anymore. Not a good answer.