# Xcode 9 running app on iOS 10.1.1 crashes on launch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I developed an app targeting iOS 10.0+ but tested only on devices & simulators running iOS 11.0+.

I hooked up an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.1.1, hit `Run` and the app crashes on launch with no error logged in the console, just crashes on `AppDelegate`.

A discovery I made, is when I went to my storyboard and made a totally empty `ViewController` as the `Initial ViewController`, the app runs perfectly.
I have set other screens I have developed as the `Initial ViewController`, some crash and some don't.
I don't see any difference among those screens at all (not in the VCs settings or the classes).

What could be the issue? I am totally frustrated :(

**Edit: I have tried the following things: Delete & Reinstall the app, Clean CMD+Shift+K & Run, delete the Xcode's Derived Data. None of it worked.**

**Edit 2: I have downloaded a 10.1 simulator and I am getting this error in the log:**

```
[] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash_libsystem libsystem simulate crash unavailable "libsystem_network.dylib: nw_host_stats_add_src :: received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument"
2017-10-25 16:39:22.478543 Tuttnauer Wi-Fi Connect[40460:11666750] [] nw_host_stats_add_src received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.20.4
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000104eeb682 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libsystem_network.dylib             0x0000000104f02306 nw_get_host_stats + 1083
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010669578b nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 1382
    3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104c68980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104c920cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104c6fe6b _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104c70b9f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104c733b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104c7308b _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001050451ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000105044c4d start_wqthread + 13
```

[image]

Comment: uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: What is your crash log ? Did you tried to add `Exception breakpoint` and see where program stopped ?

Comment: Hi, please check my updated question :)

Comment: You should look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273773/nw-host-stats-add-src-recv-too-small-received-24-expected-28

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the ViewController in Interface Builder has Builds for set for 11.0. Changing it to Deployment Target fixes the issue.

[image: Build Setting]

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I also had the same scenerio. @vanna

Answer (score 1):

reference from https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48959

One of methods how to resolve that is:

- Close Xcode
- Go to: /Users/YourOSXUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Delete all folders from "Driver Data"
- Open Xcode, open project and build again.

it's work for me, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue because the custom class for he nib file isn't correct.

**Show Identify Inspector** -> **Class**

set it to your customized class.

[image]