# AWS iOS call works but strange output to Debug

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, debugging, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS User Pools.
I have:

```
func refreshDetails(_ user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser) -> AWSTask<AnyObject> {

    return user.getDetails().continueWith(block: task -> Any? in

       /*
           here, task.result is AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse
           and task.result.userAttributes is correctly set
       */

        return task
    })
}
```

After `getDetails()` is called and the handler is called, the Debug window output complains of an `Invalid argument`:

```
2018-01-24 16:15:09.843031 gc develop[49753:1784483] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash_libsystem libsystem simulate crash unavailable "libsystem_network.dylib: nw_host_stats_add_src :: received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument"
2018-01-24 16:15:09.843799 gc develop[49753:1784483] [] nw_host_stats_add_src received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument, dumping backtrace:
        [i386] libnetcore-856.20.4
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x07269161 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libsystem_network.dylib             0x07280647 nw_get_host_stats + 1049
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x07548d55 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 1560
    3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x070073ee _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x07032cc3 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0700f449 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1619
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0700fc5d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1109
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x07012639 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 470
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x070123fb _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 143
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x073b1fdc _pthread_wqthread + 1356
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x073b1a6a start_wqthread + 34
2018-01-24 16:15:10.065788 gc develop[49753:1784482] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash_libsystem libsystem simulate crash unavailable "libsystem_network.dylib: nw_host_stats_add_src :: received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument"
2018-01-24 16:15:10.066392 gc develop[49753:1784482] [] nw_host_stats_add_src received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument, dumping backtrace:
        [i386] libnetcore-856.20.4
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x07269161 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libsystem_network.dylib             0x07280647 nw_get_host_stats + 1049
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x07548d55 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 1560
    3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x070073ee _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x07032cc3 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0700f449 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1619
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0700fc5d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1109
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x07012639 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 470
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x070123fb _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 143
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x073b1fdc _pthread_wqthread + 1356
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x073b1a6a start_wqthread + 34
2018-01-24 16:15:10.825690 gc develop[49753:1784482] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash_libsystem libsystem simulate crash unavailable "libsystem_network.dylib: nw_host_stats_add_src :: received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument"
2018-01-24 16:15:10.826126 gc develop[49753:1784482] [] nw_host_stats_add_src received error for SRC_ADDED: [22] Invalid argument, dumping backtrace:
        [i386] libnetcore-856.20.4
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x07269161 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libsystem_network.dylib             0x07280647 nw_get_host_stats + 1049
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x07548d55 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 1560
    3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x070073ee _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x07032cc3 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0700f449 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1619
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0700fc5d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1109
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x07012639 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 470
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x070123fb _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 143
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x073b1fdc _pthread_wqthread + 1356
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x073b1a6a start_wqthread + 34
(lldb)
```

This happens on the Simulator but not when running on hardware.

Comment: might be related to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929989/xcode-9-running-app-on-ios-10-1-1-crashes-on-launch)

Comment: it seems to be unrelated to AWS if you search for the specific error from your logs here at stackoverflow or google

Comment: It might go away when the next Xcode is released.